# Dont know how to Select Cell Range For SLOPE Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Here is my problem. I want to use =SLOPE formula with a cell range that refers to another sheet with criteria: Date period between Oct-21 until Apr-22, the known_ys = Emiten Name and known_xs = IHSG.
I use this formula:

`=SLOPE(IF(AND(Emiten!B:B>=Risk!$A$2;Emiten!B:B<=Risk!$B$2;Emiten!A:A=Risk!D17);Emiten!D:D);IF(AND(Indeks!B:B>=Risk!$A$2;Indeks!B:B<=Risk!$B$2;Indeks!A:A=Risk!$D$2);Indeks!D:D))`

But it shows the result #VALUE!, can anyone please tell me where's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Separate it into bits and find out which part fails.

Comment: In the **Formulas** tab, go to **Evaluate Formula** in the **Formula Auditing** section. It will step you through your formula so that you can see which part is failing.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using Evaluate Formula before reducing the ranges referenced. Trying to step through a formula which is processing arrays of more than a million elements is not making life easy.

Answer (score 2):

`AND` only ever returns a **single value**. To simulate 'and' conditions within array constructions, use nested `IF` statements.

Also, you should not be using entire column references for such a construction, since it will be forced to process several million rows unnecessarily.

Try:

`=SLOPE(IF(Emiten!B1:B10>=Risk!A2,IF(Emiten!B1:B10<=Risk!B2,IF(Emiten!A1:A10=Risk!D17,Emiten!D1:D10))),IF(Indeks!B1:B10>=Risk!A2,IF(Indeks!B1:B10<=Risk!B2,IF(Indeks!A1:A10=Risk!D2,Indeks!D1:D10))))`

adjusting the last row referenced (10 here) to a suitably low, though sufficient, upper bound.

Also, I take it you are aware that the `SLOPE` function will only consider rows for which **both** the *known_ys* and the *known_xs* are numeric? For example, assuming that the above resolved to:

| known_ys | known_xs |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | FALSE |
| 53 | FALSE |
| FALSE | 27 |
| FALSE | FALSE |
| 16 | 63 |
| 58 | 90 |
| FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 80 | 85 |
| 25 | 40 |

then `SLOPE` would ignore everything apart from the the 5th, 6th, 9th and 10th pairs, effectively calculating over the following reduced array:

| known_ys | known_xs |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 63 |
| 58 | 90 |
| 80 | 85 |
| 25 | 40 |

Comment: Some really good info about the slope function in your answer, neat.